# Supabase JavaScript data fetching with nested select

Tags: supabase, supabase-database, supabase-js

I am new to [supabase](https://supabase.com/) and data fetching via supabase-js client.

When I have the tables below and I have to fetch votes and additionally data from the result and club table, how does this work? Respectively is it possible to have **nested selects**? Unfortunately I could not find an example in https://supabase.com/docs/guides/api/joins-and-nesting or https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/select.

From Prisma I know it can be realized with nested includes as described [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#create-a-single-record-and-multiple-related-records). Is this possible in supabase too?

**Voting table**

| id | title | result_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Voting title 1 | 1 |
| 2 | Voting title 2 | 2 |

**Result table**

| id | yes | no | club_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 300 | 406 | 1 |
| 2 | 21 | 12 | 2 |
| 2 | 265 | 201 | 3 |

**Club table**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Club A |
| 2 | Club B |
| 3 | Club C |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an example for querying nested tables in the docs that you liked right here. https://supabase.com/docs/guides/api/joins-and-nesting

You can query them like this:

```js
const {data, error} = await supabase.from('votes').select('*, results(*, clubs(*))')
```